# Why can't RX add to alkenes / alkynes like HX?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, reactivity, c-c-addition

With an analogous mechanism: C bonded to X has a δ+ charge and attacks the pi electrons to form a carbocation intermediate, with X<sup>-</sup> as a leaving group. X<sup>-</sup> then adds to the carbocation to neutralize it.

Why doesn't this occur?

If steric hinderance is the answer, what about MeX adding to a terminal alkyne?
RCH2X + OH<sup>-</sup> → RCH2OH + X<sup>-</sup> proceeds (with comparable/less hinderance?) so it seems unlikely that this the reason.

H-X bonds are more polar than C-X, but the electronegativity difference between C and H is small enough that we consider C-H bonds nonpolar. Electron-deficient C can pull some electron density from adjacent carbons if there are any - but again, what about MeX? Is the presence of 3 hydrogens enough to stabilize the C-X bond to the extent that the addition doesn't take place?

Comment: Well, something like that happens in Friedel-Crafts alkylation, but you need a catalyst. To protonate alkene (or alkyne) you need a very strong acid. Similarly you need very strong alkylating agent and MeX isn't strong.

Comment: @Mithoron What factor necessitates use of a catalyst? Autoionization of water seems less favorable and occurs at RTP. Adding R-X has the potential to generate a more substituted carbocation than H-X, with the same leaving group.
What makes the transition state for this reaction so high-energy?

I am just trying to understand this conceptually. If I saw this on paper, how would I know no reaction occurs?

Comment: "Autoionization of water seems less favorable"? Only seems. Oxonium cations are waaay more stable than carbenium cations (typical carbocations like CH3+). For starters they have full octet.

Comment: @Mithoron That's what I was missing. Thanks.